# fullpage.js last slide half height

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

My last slide is my footer, it has a small height. How can i make so that when you scroll to the last slide, the footer shows and the rest of the available height is filled by the upper slide. that way it scrolls just enough to see the full footer while still being able to see a % of the upper slide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example on the fullpage.js doc website that do just what you want: [fullpage.js Auto-Height example](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/autoHeight.html#3rdPage)

I have not tried it but from my understanding you simply have to add the CSS class `fp-auto-height` to your footer section.